# Deploying Flask API on Azure Functions - exceptions not captured

Tags: python-3.x, azure, flask, azure-functions

I'm learning how to deploy Flask API app on Azure with Azure Functions.

I have created following wsgi.py file:

```
from app import create_app
from error_handler import default_error_handler_azure_functions
from flask import jsonify

app = create_app()


@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def handle_error(e):
    return default_error_handler_azure_functions(e)
```

Here's the function_app.py script required by the Azure Functions service:

```
import azure.functions as func
from flask import Flask, request, Response, redirect, url_for
from wsgi import app

app = func.WsgiFunctionApp(app=app.wsgi_app, http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
```

The app.py script looks like this:

```
import api
import mongoengine
import flask
from flask_cors import CORS
from error_handler import default_error_handler_azure_functions


def create_app():
    app = flask.Flask(__name__)
    CORS(app)
    app.config.from_prefixed_env()
    app.register_blueprint(api.blueprint)

    if not "TESTING" in app.config or not app.config["TESTING"]:
        mongoengine.connect(host=app.config["MONGO_URI"], name="finapp")

    app.register_error_handler(Exception, default_error_handler_azure_functions)

    return app
```

The simple error handler looks like this:

```
def default_error_handler_azure_functions(e: Exception):
    code = 499

    ret = {
        "Error": "InternalServerError",
        "Description": "Unknown error occurred while processing your request.",
        "Resolution": "Try again later.",
    }

    if isinstance(e, Error):
        code = e.get_code()
        ret = e.get_json()

    return flask.jsonify(ret), code
```

Everything works properly when run in the Azure's App Service or locally with:

```
app = create_app()
app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0")
```

When any exception is raised in the application, it is captured by this error handler. However in Azure Functions, exceptions are not captured. It looks like the handler is not called - in logs on Azure I can see the exception is raised and not handled so the server returns 500 Internal Server Error.

My requirements.txt file:

```
Flask==2.2.2
PyJWT==2.1.0
python-dotenv==0.19.2
pytest==7.1.3
dnspython==1.16.0
flask-restful==0.3.9
mongomock==4.1.2
pytest-cov==4.0.0
black==22.10.0
multipledispatch==0.6.0
mongoengine==0.24.2
iso4217==1.11.20220401
iso18245==1.2.0
pycountry==22.3.5
flask-cors==3.0.10
openapi-core==0.18.2
Werkzeug==2.2.2
aiosmtpd==1.4.4.post2
azure-functions
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you please share your folder structure

Comment: Also provide the complete code of `function_app.py` file in order to help you better

Comment: The function_app.py is paste 1:1 above, there's nothing more in that script, just few imports and a single line with `app = func.WsgiFunctionApp(app=app.wsgi_app, http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)`. All modules/scripts (error_handler.py, app.py, wsgi.py and function_app.py) are in the root directory of the project.

Comment: please share code of `app.py` file and screenshot of your folder structure

Comment: I have updated the post with app.py body

Comment: can you please share your requirements.txt file?

Comment: I have updated the post with requirements.txt

Comment: I have used your code and deployed it to function app but post deployment I am able to see the Exception messages while triggering the function like [this](https://i.imgur.com/6hnJPvy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used your code and able to get the expected response when the `error_handler` is invoked.

In my case `host.json` file looks like below-

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"
  },
  "extensions": 
  {
    "http": 
    {
        "routePrefix": ""
    }
  }
}
```

I have deployed my function to function app and got successfully deployed message.

[image]

[image]

I can see all the related files in the function app.

[image]

I am getting the excepted error message along with the error code while triggering the function.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Would you mind adding your code to a public Github repository? I could compare differences then.  Thank you!

Comment: @VIPPER Here is the [Github link](https://github.com/PravallikaKothaveerannagari/77822090), I have made some changes for testing purpose

Comment: Thanks. I checked out your repository and it worked without a problem. Then, I copied it into my project and it was still failing. After few experiments, it came out I'm using my requirements.txt file instead of yours. When replaced to yours, it started working. Finally, I discovered that updating Flask module from 2.2.2 to 3.0.0 resolved the problem. Thanks a lot for your support on this!